# List of lists as a query param

Tags: spring, http

How do I declare a controller method that takes a list of lists as a query param? And how do I call it then?

I specifically mean something along the lines of

```kotlin
suspend fun v1GetSearch( @PathVariable("id") id: String, @Valid @RequestParam(value = "options", required = false) options: List<List<String>>?): ResponseEntity<SearchResponse>
```

And then I'd like to call it like:

```
http://localhost:8080/search/id?options=[["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"],["abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd"]]
```

Is this possible?

I've seen other questions about the same thing, but a lot of answers always resort to suggesting POST instead of GET and send the list of lists through the request body. This is not an option in my case, since I want the endpoint to be fully idempotent and cacheable.

Comment: I'd say it's a bad idea.  Too much data in plain text that will live forever in a server log and perhaps be exploited.  No encryption or protection possible.

Comment: They're just filter options for a view of a resource, nothing sensitive or identifiable

Comment: Still a bad idea in my view.  Don't queries have a length limit - 2048 bytes?

Comment: The inner arrays are always 2 elements long. The outer array is usually one, or two arrays long. Five at most.

Comment: you should be able to call the endpoint that you mentioned in the question like this: `/search/123?options[0][0]=foo&options[0][1]=bar&options[1][0]=baz&options[1][1]=qux`. But better to switch to a POST body rather than a list of lists as query param.

Answer (score 1):

As duffymo said it's not good idea to send many data on param . but if I want answer your question , you can create a class or record(if your are using jdk14 or above ) as following:

```
    public class YourParamDto{
     private list<String> listOne;
     private list<String> listTwo;
//constructor ,getterand setter methods ...
}
```

then in controller class use it as bellow :

```
suspend fun v1GetSearch( @PathVariable("id") id: String, @Valid @RequestParam(value = "options", required = false) options: YourParamDto): ResponseEntity<SearchResponse>
```

so your get request will be as :

```
http://localhost:8080/search/id?listOne=["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd"]&listOne=["abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd"]
```

Comment: This is the solution I arrived at... though it isn't very ergonomic. I want to stress that the sizes of the arrays is known to be within small bounds so I don't think there'll be any issues with that in practice